# Does Alamofire support prioritization?

Tags: alamofire

I want to know if Alamofire supports prioritization of requests. Something similar to `URLSessionTask` property. Here is a link Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1410569-priority)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not. The prioritization supported by `URLSessionTask` is just a hint to the server about possible resource priorities, usually used by web browsers. It isn't typically effective or necessary for REST APIs, which is Alamofire's primary use case.